# Does LWJGL (bare) use software or hardware rendering?

Tags: rendering, hardware, lwjgl

Does the bare LWJGL distribution use hardware rendering or software rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LWJGL always uses hardware rendering. Since it is a games library, it just quits if no hardware rendering is available.

From the LWJGL wiki: "Made the library throw an exception when hardware acceleration is not available on Windows. No point in running at 5fps is there? "([LWJGL wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20120325121754/http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=About_LWJGL))

There is a command-line switch `org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL` but I don't think you can force it to use software rendering.

Comment: Has that wiki gone down? Do you have another reference that it's impossible to force lwjgl to use software rendering when hardware is available?

Comment: Updated the link to point to a copy from The Wayback Machine, but the answer is from 2011 so it may be out of date.